# File not found error using subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using python 3.6.9 on my ubuntu 18.04LTS install and trying to use the subprocess library to call a compiled C++ function. The function takes no arguments so I would figure this should work:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ais"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but doing so returns

```
>>> Popen(["ais"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ais': 'ais'
```

This is a little confusing to me given that calling `os.listdir()` from the same directory returns:

```
>>> print(os.listdir())
['COM6 ARPA_A.txt', 'dataStream.py', 'arpa.cpp', 'arpa', 'COM7 AIS.txt', 'ais.cpp', 'ais']
```

Comment: Unless `cwd` (or `.`) is in the current `PATH` you wouldn't have been able to type out `ais` in the shell and have your program execute, you would have had to type out `./ais`.  So do the same thing and run `Popen(["./ais"])` instead.  This of course assumes `ais` has the executable bit set.

Comment: Oh wow I thought for sure I had tried that, but yes that was it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing a file you have to use './filename'

from reading your above comment, you have to give executable permission to the file which can be done as:

```
chmod +x ais
```

Reason for which is well explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432/399463